# Passing parameters to mutator functions in Scala

Tags: scala, mutators

I'm playing around in Scala to try and get the hang of it, so this code sample is simply academic.

I'm trying to pass a mutable List to a function, have that function perform work on it, and then after the function call I can use the updated list.

```
var data: List[Int] = List()

// Call to function to fill a list
data = initList(data)

// Output only 0-100
data.foreach( num => if (num < 100) { println(num) })

def initList(var data: List[Int]) : List[Int] = {

    for ( i <- 0 to 1000 )
    {
        data = i :: data
    }

    data = data.reverse
    data
}
```

The only code above that doesn't compile is the `var` in `def initList()`, and because data is then a `val` I cannot perform any mutations to it within the function.

Let me start by saying that I know in Scala, mutators are usually frowned upon, so I'm not only open to a direct answer to my question, but open to better ways to do it entirely. Occasionally in projects there is a piece of data that goes from place to place to be updated, but if you cannot pass data to a function to be changed then what is a good alternative?

I've read through tutorials and google'd for this, I'm assuming I can't find much about it because it's not usually done this way in Scala.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first important thing to realize is that while `data` is a var, the list itself is still immutable.  While you can assign a new list to `data`, you cannot alter the actual list itself.  This is also why you cannot pass a list to a function and have the list altered.  So actually your `for` loop is creating a new list with each iteration.

Luckily, Scala makes it really easy to write functional code to create Lists and other immutable data structures.  Here's the general "functional" way to do what you want:

```
def initList(data: List[Int]) = {
  def initLoop(num: Int, buildList: List[Int]): List[Int] = num match {
    case 0 => 0 :: buildList
    case n => initLoop(n - 1, n :: buildList)
  }
  initLoop(1000, data)
}
```

Basically what's happening here is I replaced the for loop with a tail-recursive function.  With each call, the inner function is building a new list by taking the current list and prepending the next number, until it gets to 0 and returns the finished list.  Since the function starts at 1000 and goes backwards to 0, the list doesn't have to be reversed.

To give you an idea of how this works, here's the values of the inner function's parameters at each recursive call (though let's start at 3 instead of 1000):

```
initLoop(3, data)
initLoop(2, 3 :: data)
initLoop(1, 2 :: 3 :: data)
initLoop(0, 1 :: 2 :: 3 :: data)
```

so when it finally gets to 0, it returns (assuming data was empty) `List(0, 1, 2, 3)`

This method is actually faster than using the for loop since you don't need to reverse the list at the end.  Scala is able to optimize tail-recursive functions so you don't have to worry about stack overflow or out-of-memory errors.

There's a ton of other ways to create and transform lists, I also could have done this:

```
val data: List[Int] = List()
(0 to 1000).foldRight(data){ (num, buildList) => num :: buildList}
```

or even just this:

```
(0 to 1000).toList
```

Answer (score 4):

You should prefer the functional/immutable solution as suggested in the other answers. However when you really need this facility - to pass a value by reference, you can use [ML style mutable reference cells](http://batteries.forge.ocamlcore.org/doc.preview%3abatteries-beta1/html/api/Ref.html).

This is how you declare them:

```
val cell: Ref[SomeClass] = Ref(value)
```

This is how you access their value:

```
!cell
```

And this is how you change their value:

```
cell := !cell + 1
// OR
cell.modify(_ + 1)
```

---

A simple reference-cell implementation:

```
final class Ref[A] private(private var a: A) {
  def :=(newValue: A): Unit = {
    a = newValue
  }

  def unary_! : A = a

  def modify(f: A => A): Unit = {
    a = f(a)
  }
}

object Ref {
  def apply[A](value: A) = new Ref(value)
}
```

You can add many useful methods to this. e.g. increment, decrement for integral values.

This is your code rewritten using reference cells (works as expected):

```
def initList(data: Ref[List[Int]]): Unit = {
  for(i <- 0 to 1000)
    data := i :: !data
  data := (!data).reverse
}

val data = Ref(List.empty[Int])
initList(data)    
for(num <- !data; if num < 100)
  println(num)
```

Answer (score 2):

How about something like this:

```
def initList(inData: List[Int]) : List[Int] = {
    var data = inData  // <----The one added line
    for ( i <- 0 to 1000 )
    {
        data = i :: data
    }
    data.reverse
}
```

Comment: That did the trick, I can't believe the answer to the problem is to make a mutable copy of a immutable copy of a mutable variable. Is there a way to do this without the copy? Or is this considered standard practice with Scala?

Comment: Well, this actually copies very little; declaring 'data' as a var was simply you saying that the reference that data points to can be changed.  'inData' is basically a val by default, so it shares the same reference as 'data' for its lifespan (or, at least the same reference as was originally passed into the function), and then initList#data also adopts that very same reference initially—that's three things that simultaneously have that same reference!—but it is then continually overwritten by the for{} loop.

Comment: So... is there another way?  Yeah... there are other ways, but I don't think that any are more practical than this.  Its cost is very little, and it accomplishes what you want.

Answer (score 2):

What might be better code is

```
val data = 1000 to 0 by -1
```

Much faster in (imo) easier to read.